# How to Change the Animation Speed of a Windows.Controls (WPF) ProgressBar

Tags: wpf-controls, progress-bar

I have a fairly short and indeterminate process which needs a quicker-than-standard animation speed. I couldn't find any likely properties, or even anything on the net.

Anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something specific you could always create your own control that looks like a progress bar and animate as desired.

However, if it's a short process you may want to reconsider the need to display progress or display it in a different way.

Comment: Fair call. I'm now using a wait cursor instead. Thx for flexing my mind. :-)